# Selenium Java POM

Tags: java, selenium, pom.xml

I’ve created a framework in selenium with design pattern “page object model”
But I want all classes to be executed in the same web browser and what is happening is each class is run and the browser window closed then another one is opened for the next class

I need all classes to be run in the same browser.

Comment: If you are using TestNG, check the methods with the annotations - '@BeforeClass' and '@AfterClass' or '@BeforeMethod' and '@AfterMethod'. Those methods contain the code to launch the browser before each test case and quit the browser after that test case. Modify that according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement before and after test method which launch the browser before every test and kill it afterwards.
Something like this:

```
    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEachTest(TestInfo testInfo) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
      
    }

  @Test
 void yourTestLogic(){
Actual test here
}

    @AfterEach
    void afterEachTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

This is JUnit 5 example. The same is possible with TestNG with very small differences.